# Selecting multiple options in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a code in SQL for Access. The query asks three questions. I have three categories -- I'll just use the categories 'country', 'city', 'street' for now. I am trying to figure out how to make it so that you only have to enter one answer even though it asks you 3. But if you answer two, it will give you the like terms. For example, if I answered Georgia and Atlanta, Atlanta Georgia would show up. Or if I entered Canal in 'street' and Louisiana, every street named Canal in Louisiana would show up.

Currently, if I typed out Canal and Louisiana, the query would show me everything listed under Louisiana and every street titled Canal (even the ones not in Louisiana).

```
SELECT * 
FROM File 
WHERE (((File.State)=[Enter the state])) 
    OR (((File.City)=[Enter the city])) 
    OR (((File.Street)=[Enter the street]));
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This is what I have so far:                                                              
SELECT *
FROM File
WHERE (((File.State)=[Enter the state])) OR (((File.City)=[Enter the city])) OR (((File.Street)=[Enter the street]));

Comment: Sorry for the weird formatting, I don't know how to go to a new line.

Comment: Simply use a form to send dynamic parameters to query. Do not use a query for user input.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a form in this situation.

Comment: Can I ask why not? If you were to call this query via ODBC with VBA or other languages, query will error out due to missing parameters. The *[Enter Parameter]* dialog is generally a reminder for missing parameter not designed for user interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do it by using AND rather than OR to connect the criteria for the different columns, but not using the criteria for a column if its parameter wasn't given.

```
SELECT * 
FROM File 
WHERE   ( ([Enter the state] = '') OR (File.State=[Enter the state]) ) 
    AND ( ([Enter the city] = '') OR (File.City=[Enter the city]) )
    AND ( ([Enter the street] = '') OR (File.Street=[Enter the street]) );
```

I'm kind of rusty with Access, so I'm not sure if the parameter will be `null` or `''` if nothing is entered, so it might need to be adjusted a little for that.

Comment: It should be Is Null - This is the correct answer. ` ( ([Enter the state] Is Null) OR (File.State=[Enter the state]) ) `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM File WHERE
(((File.State)='[Enter the state]'))
    OR (((File.City)='[Enter the city]'))
    OR (((File.Street)='[Enter the street]'));
```

You just needed some quotes around them because they are strings.

Comment: When I put the quotes around that, it doesn't run the query in Access. My trouble wasn't with getting it to run, whenever I entered a state, city, or street, the query would return what I asked for. But what I am trying to figure out how to do is join the two responses. So if I typed Georgia and Peach for 'street', every street in Georgia names Peach would show up rather than everything for Georgia and every street out there named Peach showing up.

Does that make sense?

Comment: If i'm understanding, just change the OR's to AND's

Comment: That's what I also tried, but then it requires me to fill out all fields and if I don't it just returns a blank query. I still want it to be option to answer all 3 questions but if you answer more than 1, it will filter it like I explained

Comment: I cant think of a way to do that in a single select statement. But it would be simple to create a form with those 3 boxes and write some VBA that would build the select statement based on checking the contents of the boxes.

Comment: I am not very familiar with forms or VBA so I'll have to look into how to do that.